# Выборка строк, в которых 2 слова

Tags: sql

Есть таблица с названиями книг.
Нужно выбрать лишь те названия книг, в которых имеется ровно один пробел, то есть ровно 2 слова.
Запрос вида:

```
Select name
From books
where name like '%[ ]%'
```

Выбирает строки с 2мя и более словами. А нужно ровно с 2мя.

Comment: `WHERE LENGTH(name)-LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')) = 1` или `WHERE name NOT LIKE '%[ ]%[ ]%'`.

Comment: НастоящимПрограммистам_пробелы-не%нужны.(с) Я к тому, что "два слова" != "наличие строго пробела(ов) между словами"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    [String] 
FROM (VALUES ('Тут одинПробел'),('Тут два пробела'), ('Тут сноваОдин')) T(String)
WHERE LEN([String])-LEN(REPLACE([String],' ',''))=1
```

Comment: Можна использовать и такое условие 
               where CHARINDEX(' ', [String], CHARINDEX(' ', [String]) + 1)=0

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name
From books
where name like '%[ ]%' and name not like '%[ ]%[ ]%'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]